# Install MarkLogic extensions

Tags: installation, marklogic

How do I install MarkLogic extensions?  I want to be able to use the OOXML library in the "http://marklogic.com/openxml" namespace.  How do I integrate that?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's what I'm trying to do in the console:

```
import module namespace ooxml= "http://marklogic.com/openxml" at
       "/MarkLogic/openxml/word-processing-ml-support.xqy";
let $para1 := ooxml:create-paragraph("Hello, World!")
let $para2 := ooxml:create-paragraph("Welcome to Unit 6!")
let $paras := ($para1, $para2)
return xdmp:save("/path/to/test.docx",ooxml:create-simple-docx(ooxml:document(ooxml:body($paras))))
```

What I'm getting is the following:

```
[1.0-ml] SVC-FILOPN: File open error: open 'Apps/MarkLogic/openxml/word-processing-ml-support.xqy': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like it says at http://docs.marklogic.com/ooxml:package-parts

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace ooxml= "http://marklogic.com/openxml" 
      at "/MarkLogic/openxml/package.xqy";

let $pkg := xdmp:document-get("c:/tmp/test.docx")
return ooxml:package-parts($pkg)
```

Comment: See my edit above.  (Your code works, but I'm trying to build .docx files).

Comment: The error message is telling you that MarkLogic can't find `word-processing-ml-support.xqy`. I think that file comes with the http://developer.marklogic.com/code/marklogic-toolkit-for-word - the Toolkit for Word? Take a look at "XQuery Libraries" in the ToolkitForWordGuide.docx from the zip. It describes how to copy the xqy files to the `/Modules/MarkLogic/openxml` in your MarkLogic install directory.